# Efficient way to speed up the code - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, loops, data-science

I have the below sample example where I have used a dummy URL

```
account_list = ['aacc14-27','aacc14-26','aacc13-25','cad5r-98']
appended_data = []
for i in account_list:
    url = 'http://22.45.78:8000/transactions?accountId='+i
    x = pd.read_json(url)
    appended_data.append(x)
```

The speed of the above code is not very quick. Is there a better way to improve the overall speed of the loop for processing data?

Comment: Complexity is to the O(n). Looks fine to me.

Comment: Why are you making a list of single value dataframes?

Comment: I guess the value taking part here will be the external call. You should do them somehow in parallel( most likely with threads) and combine the result afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python multiprocessing, for example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


url = 'http://22.45.78:8000/transactions?accountId='

def load_json(account, data):
    x = pd.read_json(url+account)
    data.append(x)

account_list = ['aacc14-27','aacc14-26','aacc13-25','cad5r-98']

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
manager = mp.Manager()

appended_data = manager.list()

[pool.apply_async(load_json, args=[e,appended_data]) for e in account_list]
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(appended_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!! The above code  improved  my processing speed by few seconds.